# subprocess.Popen() sends awk and grep lines differently than expected

Tags: python, linux, awk, subprocess

On a CentOS 7.2 I have a file called cpuload, which contains the latest CPU load data in the following format:

```
last 30 sec:
average load: 0
cpu0 total load:     0
cpu1 total load:     0
cpu2 total load:     0
cpu3 total load:     1
cpu4 total load:     0
cpu5 total load:     0
cpu6 total load:     0
cpu7 total load:     0

last sec:
average load: 1
cpu0 total load:     5
cpu1 total load:     1
cpu2 total load:     1
cpu3 total load:     3
cpu4 total load:     2
cpu5 total load:     1
cpu6 total load:     0
cpu7 total load:     0
```

I want to get the number after the "average load:" of the "last sec" bit.
Two cli commands give me that information when I run them as shell commands on the terminal:
`grep 'average load:' cpuload | sed -n 's/.*load: //p' | tail -n1`
and
`awk 'NR > 2 && /average load:/ {print $3}' cpuload`

But when I run them in subprocess.Popen() with Shell=True I only get stderr:

for:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ["grep", "'average load:'", "cpuload", "|", "sed", "-n", "'s/.*load: //p'", "|", "tail", "-n1"]
test = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
test.stderr.read()
```

I get:

```
b"Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...\nTry 'grep --help' for more information.\n"
```

and for:

```
import subprocess
    
cmd = cmd = ["awk", "'NR > 2 && /average load:/ {print $3}'", "cpuload"]
test = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
test.stderr.read()
```

I also get:

```
b"awk: cmd. line:1: 'NR > 2 && /average load:/ {print $3}'\nawk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression\n"
```

Even though I avoided using a |

or if `shell=True` I get:

```
b"Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...\nUsage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...\nPOSIX options:\t\tGNU long options: (standard)\n\t-f progfile\t\t--file=progfile\n\t-F fs\t\t\t--field-separator=fs\n\t-v var=val\t\t--assign=var=val\nShort options:\t\tGNU long options: (extensions)\n\t-b\t\t\t--characters-as-bytes\n\t-c\t\t\t--traditional\n\t-C\t\t\t--copyright\n\t-d[file]\t\t--dump-variables[=file]\n\t-e 'program-text'\t--source='program-text'\n\t-E file\t\t\t--exec=file\n\t-g\t\t\t--gen-pot\n\t-h\t\t\t--help\n\t-L [fatal]\t\t--lint[=fatal]\n\t-n\t\t\t--non-decimal-data\n\t-N\t\t\t--use-lc-numeric\n\t-O\t\t\t--optimize\n\t-p[file]\t\t--profile[=file]\n\t-P\t\t\t--posix\n\t-r\t\t\t--re-interval\n\t-S\t\t\t--sandbox\n\t-t\t\t\t--lint-old\n\t-V\t\t\t--version\n\nTo report bugs, see node `Bugs' in `gawk.info', which is\nsection `Reporting Problems and Bugs' in the printed version.\n\ngawk is a pattern scanning and processing language.\nBy default it reads standard input and writes standard output.\n\nExamples:\n\tgawk '{ sum += $1 }; END { print sum }' file\n\tgawk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd\n"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `invalid char ''' in expression` seems pretty clear. Surely you can do whatever you're trying to do in python though rather than spawning a subshell to call other tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with passing the awk parameter to subprocess with ' around them, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607829/invalid-char-in-expression-awk-python)

Did not accept Ed Morton's comment as it did not specify what should have been done.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a file called cpuload, which contains the latest CPU load data  ...I want to get the number after the "average load:" of the "last sec" bit

why not just to use simple python code in order to get the value you are looking for?

```
with open('cpuload') as f:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
    got_it = False
    for line in lines:
        if got_it:
            parts = line.split(':')
            result = parts[-1].strip()
            print(result)
            break
        if line == 'last sec:':
            got_it = True
```

output

```
1
```

Comment: This reads the entire file into memory unnecessary, and makes a lot of boolean checks that can be avoided. `lines = itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x != "last sec:", (l.strip() for l in f)); next(lines); parts = next(lines).split(':'); ...`.

Comment: I agree. If it's a small it is not that important. For a larger one it can make an impact.

Comment: The utility that checks the cpu load and writes to the file is a C-written piece of software which is one part of the larger product of my company that sits on this machine. It is closer to the "bare metal" of the machine and works faster and more efficient than python would.

Comment: If the file is not huge - I dont see any reason not to use python.

Comment: Well, the question was not about that. If you can provide an explenation why the cli command works but the subprocess.Popen() version doesn't, it'll be more educational and helpful.
If push comes to shove I will use something like this (though I'll look for something resembling a stream rather than pour the file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

First case with `grep`, `sed`, `tail`... and pipes.
You need to use `shell = True` parameter for `Popen` method and a single string for the command. We need to put cotes around parameters:

```py
import subprocess
cmd = "grep 'average load:' cpuload | sed -n 's/.*load: //p' | tail -n1"
output = ""
test = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
while True:
    output += test.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8")
    if test.poll() is not None:
        break
print("output=<%s>" % (output))
```

Second case, without pipe:
You don't need to use `shell = True` parameter for `Popen` method and a single string for the command. We don't put cotes around parameters:

```py
import subprocess

cmd = ["/usr/bin/awk", "NR > 2 && /^average load:/ {print $3}", "cpuload"]
output = ""
test = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    output += test.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8")
    if test.poll() is not None:
        break
print("output=<%s>" % (output))
```

Comment: Not only did you not read that I specifically mentioned I used shell=True in my pipe code, your code snippets don't work. They each print out: `output=<>`